# Identity involving sum of $_4F_3$ hypergeometric functions with unit argument

Tags: special-functions, hypergeometric-function

I've found that this identity seems to be true for all positive integers $n$:
$$1=
\,_4F_3\left(\frac{1}{6},\frac{5}{6},\frac{1}{2}-\frac{n}{2},1-\frac{n}{2};\frac{3}{2},\frac{5}{6}-\frac{n}{2},\frac{7
   }{6}-\frac{n}{2};1\right)2\frac{\left(\frac{n+1}{2}\right)_{n-1}
}{\left(\frac{n}{2}+1\right)_{n-1}}\\
-\,_4F_3\left(-\frac{1}{3},\frac{1}{3},\frac{1}{2}-\frac{n}{2},-\frac{n}{2};\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{3}-\frac{n}{2},\frac{2
   }{3}-\frac{n}{2};1\right)
$$
I've searched for identities involving the $_4F_3$ hypergeometric function but have not found anything matching this set of parameters.

Note that both hypergeometric functions are Saalschützian and their series are terminating for $n$ a positive integer.

Do you have any ideas of how to prove this is true or find an applicable identity?

The identity shows up in trying to prove that the solution found here:
https://mathoverflow.net/questions/291546/second-order-recurrence-relation-for-third-order-polynomial-root
is correct using induction. That relation in turn showed up in a quantum field theory calculation.

Best regards,
Petter

Mathematica expression for convenience:

```
0==-1 - HypergeometricPFQ[{-(1/3), 1/3, 1/2 - n/2, -(n/2)}, {1/2, 
   1/3 - n/2, 2/3 - n/2}, 1] + (
 2 HypergeometricPFQ[{1/6, 5/6, 1/2 - n/2, 1 - n/2}, {3/2, 5/6 - n/2, 
    7/6 - n/2}, 1] Pochhammer[(1 + n)/2, -1 + n])/
 Pochhammer[1 + n/2, -1 + n]
```

Comment: First guess would be Induction, did you try that?

Comment: I suppose $(a)_n$ is supposed to be the Pochhammer symbol $\Gamma(a+n)/\Gamma(a)$?

Comment: Do you mean induction in n? Proving the identity for n=k by assuming it works for n=k-1. That could be a route but I would then need to find an identity between the 4F3 functions relating different n.

Comment: Indeed, $(a)_n$ is the Pochhammer symbol, denoting the rising factorial.

Comment: Yes, to get a feeling for the thing it would probably be good to start with $n=1$ "manually".

Comment: To get upvotes for the question, thus more attention, it will be good to add some motivation how you got to the question, to the identity and what you have considered for solution. Also why do these all terminate?

Comment: The hypergeometric functions are defined through series that contains rising factorials of the arguments. For $n$ a positive integer, either $a=1/2-n/2$ or $a=1-n/2$ is a negative integer and $(a)_m$ will be equal to 0 for large enough $m$.

Comment: I wonder if it is possible to go for contiguity relations. I evaluate the parameter differences to $0,1/2,1$. I just start reading on h.g. functions, so I don't know if there are transformations from $a\to2a$ for$_nF_m(a,..)$ In that case you could have your contiguity, at least. But then I think it still would be a long way. Did you consider MO for posting, as well?

Comment: In [this publication](https://carma.newcastle.edu.au/jon/Preprints/Papers/Submitted%20Papers/Walks/Papers/gen-contiguity.pdf) are some expressions resembling in part your $_3F_4$ functions (esp. (11), (14) and (15), maybe that gives some starting point.

Comment: Did you have a look at the behaviour of the generating function in dependence of x? E.g. $ {\sum_{n}}   \;_4F_3\left(-\frac{1}{3},\frac{1}{3},\frac{1}{2}-\frac{n}{2},-\frac{n}{2};\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{3}-\frac{n}{2},\frac{2
   }{3}-\frac{n}{2};1\right) x^n$? Sometimes that helps

Comment: I think I have checked that publication, the arguments are not matching what we have. How do you propose we we use the generating function? The F(..) tends to 1/2 for large n so the generating function has a singularity at x=1, I guess I could find more properties but I don't know how that would help.